# Getting H2 MVStore when using JPA

Tags: h2

I use JPA in my application to utilize the H2 database. Now I'd like to get my hands on some internals of the H2 – the MV Store. What I currently have is JPA's EntityManager.

I'd like to run some special commands like compactMoveChunks() or getCurrentFillRate().

Comment: `getCurrentFillRate()` was removed from MVStore, an entirely outdated 1.4.199 is the last version with this method. `compactMoveChunks()` is still here, but it is not a part of API. If you want to improve data compaction, it is more reasonable to add `;RETENTION_TIME=0` to JDBC URL, but don't use this option in historic versions of H2, use some new version.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I'm stuck with 1.4.197 an no update is planned for now.

Comment: This version is too old. It doesn't track historic data versions needed by long-running queries well enough. Attempt to force data compaction in it may lead to failures.